# Altering all queries for table column

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a project for which I need to edit thousands of different queries, to add (in most cases) a `WHERE` operator to the query. The problem is that some queries are insert statements, while others are differently structured `SELECT` statements. Is there a way to change all queries in someway that they work with an extra column in each table called 'websitename'?

**Edit**

Here are some example queries which need to be changed to take an extra column into a count. (these queries have already been altered)

```
SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE `gamename` = '" . $game . "'
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`online`) < 300 AND `gamename` = '" . $game . "'
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You need to provide sample queries and a concrete explanation of what you need to accomplish.

Comment: Sounds like you're wanting to inject an additional where clause statement to say something like `WHERE websitename = 'Somevariable'`  To which the answer I have is there is no silver bullet.  You have to adjust each query independently; page by page.  Simply appending it to existing queries wouldn't work as you don't know if adding the limit could cause you to no longer get back desired records Such as null records on an outer join from a second table...  Additionally the table may not be on the query so you may have to modify it to get the needed joins so you can limit by websitename...

Comment: It makes no sense to add a `WHERE` clause to `INSERT` queries. `INSERT` is for adding new rows, not modifying existing rows, so there's nothing for `WHERE` to operate on (unless it's an `INSERT INTO tablename SELECT ... FROM othertable` query)

Comment: why cant use find and replace  using any editor..?

Comment: @safinchacko Because every query is differently structured.